# Cannot convert value type 'Configuration' to required type FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean for property freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring

Getting below error while using free-marker template in spring:pls suggest.
applicationContext.xml:

```
Dependent bean:
<bean id="domainManager" class="DomainManager">
<property name="freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean" ref="freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean"/>
<property name="sampleFile" value="sampleFile.ftl" />
</bean>
Error:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'freemarker.template.Configuration' to required type 'org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean' for property 'freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'freemarker.template.Configuration' to required type 'org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean' for property 'freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Comment: Please post your complete context.xml file and maven dependencies if you are using maven.

And also how you are using Freemarkerconfiguration in your class.

Comment: pom like below<dependency>
   <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
   <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.23</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: applicationContext:<bean id="freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
  <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/ftls"/>
  <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="true"/>
 </bean>
 <bean id="domainParamManager" class="DomainParamManager">
  <!--<property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine" />-->
  <property name="freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean" ref="freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean"/>
  <property name="vmSyncFileName" value="syncRTPTag.ftl" />
 </bean>

Comment: in classLevel: DomainManager:templateParams.put("i18n", messageSourceManager);
   //tag = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, vmFileName, templateParams);
   tag = BOFreeMakerReportsUtil.processTemplate(vmFileName, templateParams);

Comment: Utility class:public class BOFreeMakerReportsUtil {
    public static String processTemplate(final String ftlTemplate, final Map<String, Object> reportParams) {
        try {
            final Configuration configuration = new Configuration(new Version("2.3.23"));
            final Template template = new Template("template", new StringReader(ftlTemplate), configuration);
            return FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(template, reportParams);
        } catch (TemplateException e) {
        }catch(IOException io){
        }  return ""; }

Comment: erlier we were using velocity now replaced with freemarker template..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to keep the freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean in dependent beans.And use below  bean


Where ever we are using Reports keep below template class  as autowired with that class.
@Autowired
Configuration freemarkerConfiguration;
freemarkerConfiguration.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), CUSTOM_Constant.FREEMARKER_TEMP_LOCATION);
body = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(               freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate(fmTemplateName),templateParams);